# Lazarus Form Recovery for Safari?

Tags: mac, data-recovery, browser-addons, safari, forms

I use [Lazarus](http://lazarus.interclue.com/) a lot on Chrome and FireFox. Well, not a lot, but it's great for crashing when you're writing something online in a form that doesn't automatically save what you're writing. Plus, this should be default in every browser ANYway, and not built-in any web site (such as gmail).

So, is there any such option for Safari?
Does [Saft](http://haoli.dnsalias.com/Saft/) do that? Just by looking at the home page, it seems to me like bloatware to Safari 4.

Comment: You are posting a lot of really terrible and redundant threads.

Comment: @NSD wait, so are you voting on this question because of my other questions? I don't think that's how this should work, but well, I don't know. I actually like it better the "do whatever you want" way, like this. I just wanted to have more data on what people are doing, understanding what's happening so I can adjust better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of January 2011, Lazarus is planned to support Safari starting with version 3.0:

> Lazarus 3.0, currently in beta, is also available for the Chrome and Safari browsers. It's more intuitive to use, but it doesn't yet work for every form on the web, as the 2.1 version does (or close enough). We're currently waiting for the Chrome/Webkit team to fix a certain browser bug before we can handle certain very tricky types of form, for instance, the gmail message editor. ([Lazarus home page](http://lazarus.interclue.com/))

Comment: Thanks! Did you know Google have an addon with that same feature for Chrome? https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn I still haven't tried it, since I use Lazarus.