# Chrome - How do we recover the text in the text fields?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, google-chrome, memory

I have noticed that whenever I type things in the text fields of webpages, even when I close Chrome, the text will still persist on reopen.

However while Chrome was opened, I was running some emulators and stuff that basically hog a load of RAM. What happens is that when I come back to Chrome, the text in the text fields are no longer there (the text fields are now empty).

I was wondering how do I recover the text in the text fields?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/231776/how-do-i-see-a-history-of-what-ive-post-ed-in-google-chrome/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno) form recovery extension. Probably the best option out there.

[image]

Comment: This is cool but I was wondering is there anyway to recover the text that I've lost in the text fields? Like does the contents gets dumped somewhere before it gets purged?

Comment: No. Once lost it's lost.

Comment: @Pacerier then dont accept answer. There i found now some solutions, im trying also, cuz didnt had. This will help future, but to recover now! How? There isnt still answer..

Comment: [No longer available in Chrome store](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/7zzyr0/lazarus_form_recovery_is_gone_from_chrome_store/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable/trustworthy extension that currently does this. [Typio Form Recovery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/typio-form-recovery/djkbihbnjhkjahbhjaadbepppbpoedaa?hl=en) and Lazarus both appear to be dead.

[image: img from chrome webstore]

Comment: Typio has also joined the ranks of abandonware. No longer works with current Chrome versions