# Recover text on Reopen closed tab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery

It is easy to hit `close mark` when switching a tab with mouse. Chrome allows to reopen it. But, does it recover the text?

It happened to me when I was editing livejournal post. Chrome did not warn me `are you sure?` It just closed the tab and I see no my edit after reopen. Can I recover my last version from the cache?

Comment: This would only be possible is the server performed the save.  Your data is lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome - How do we recover the text in the text fields?](http://superuser.com/questions/349777/chrome-how-do-we-recover-the-text-in-the-text-fields)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That question asks about `closing/restarting the browser`. Mine question is about recovering a tab of running browswer. Or, I just do not understand that question, it is uncertain.

Comment: It would depend on a number of factors in general, some sites like (SO) make temporary saves on the server, others may use localStorage or some local side mechanism to make such saves.

Comment: @EricG I believe that livejournal uses server. But, I do not understand when javascript makes the save to server. I am asking about browser mechanism. Why do you speak about server if browsers do somehow save textarea values? I just wonder where is this cache in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Chrome extension that allows you to recover lost form input, but only from after you installed the extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/typio-form-recovery/djkbihbnjhkjahbhjaadbepppbpoedaa?hl=en