# Recover lost form data in Chrome (macOS / SIP enabled)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, data-recovery, history

I had lost form data on a website (Chrome/macOS), and was unable to follow the recommended resolution for Linux/Mac due to SIP being enabled ([relevant comment](https://superuser.com/questions/231776/how-do-i-see-a-history-of-what-ive-post-ed-in-google-chrome#comment1983718_1119310)). However, the associated page/tab was still open.

Through a bit of debugging, I was able to recover the lost data. I'll post my steps as a possible answer (*but won't mark as accepted unless there's no better alternative*).

My **question**: is there a better/easier way to get at that lost data? (without requiring a time machine to go back and install a browser add-on / disable SIP prior to the event?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Don’t close the tab you lost data on.**

1. Open Chrome dev tools on the affected tab (F12).

   1. Click the “*Memory*” tab.
   2. Select “*Heap snapshot*”.
   3. Click “*Take snapshot*” (this may take a while).

2. Select the newly created heap snapshot on the left navigation bar (likely named “*Snapshot 1*”).

   1. In the “*Constructor*” UI section, locate and expand the “*(string)*” drop-down (or set the “*Class filter*” to “*string*”).
   2. Click the “*Show all `{int}`*” button (you will need to scroll down through the top level strings).

3. Now the hard part:

   1. Hit ctrl/cmd + f to search for some part of the string you remember (try to only use 0-9/a-z characters, and near the beginning of the field - since strings are truncated).
   2. You may (or may not) find the string you’re looking for.

      - If not, play around with the search params (or manually scroll through all the string results).
      - If you do find the search result, it might not be the full string you’re looking for.
   3. Once you’ve selected the found string (in the “*Constructor*” section):

      1. In the “*Object*” section, hover over the first top level blue variable name (can be named anything).
      2. A pop-up should appear with the full string value.

         - If it doesn’t, you may need to scroll down in the “*Object*” section looking for another top level blue variable to inspect (by hovering over their name).
      3. Double click the string value to highlight, and then copy the results.

Comment: As it's been 5 months with no alternative solutions proposed since this answer was posted, I'm going to mark it as solved.

If anyone knows of a better solution, please add it!